# aix 5.3 cannot execute or load .profile automatically when login

Tags: unix, aix, .profile

I am using AIX 5.3, after I login as an Oracle user, I got a prompt to ask me to give the oracle home directory.  If I manually type in ". .profile", it would work.

My AIX team has built this new LPART for me, so I am wondering if there is a setting in AIX that cuased this error.

Thanks so much for your responses!

Comment: what's your shell? as stated in /etc/passwd

Comment: it is a korn shell: oracle:!:500:1002:Oracle:/home/oracle:/usr/bin/ksh

Answer (score 0):

How are you logging in as the Oracle user?

If you are using 'su oracle' you should issue 'su - oracle'

That will create a new shell and load .profile.